# Problem running post-install step. Error reading file postgresql.conf

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin

When I install any version of postgres (pgadmin) on my Windows 10 computer, everything is installed perfectly until it almost reaches the end of the installation and it tells me that the post installation step could not be executed and therefore the configuration can not be saved in the file postgresql.conf

And then I opened the application and when I put the password to access the server I get an error, because it does not save the user settings, password, or anything.

[image: image of the error warning that I get]

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.0? Really?

Comment: No, in all the versions that I installed 9, 10, 11